# OSX RSA Decryption from Bouncy Castle

Tags: ios, macos, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I'm attempting to decrypt data with a given private key from a Java process that is using BouncyCastle

The code that generates the private key is:

```
RSAPrivateCrtKeyParameters key = new RSAPrivateCrtKeyParameters(modulus, publicExponent, privateExponent, p, q, dP, dQ, qInv);
RSAPrivateKeyStructure struc = new RSAPrivateKeyStructure(key.getModulus(), key.getPublicExponent(), key.getExponent(), key.getP(), key.getQ(), key.getDP(), key.getDQ(), key.getQInv());
byte [] bytes = struc.getEncoded();
```

According to the documentation this should produce an RSA key in PKCS1 v2.1 format.

Here's an example output in base64

```
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
```

This appears to be correct based on what I've read of PKCS1.  I don't think the Java code is using padding -- at least I have not seen anything that says PKCS1, PKCS5, etc -- so I believe I must use "kSecPaddingNone" on iOS and Mac.

I'm attempting to decrypt this on both iOS and Mac OSX.  I have it working on iOS with

```
status = SecKeyDecrypt(key, kSecPaddingNone, (uint8_t *)[data bytes], [data length], plainBuffer, &plainBufferSize);
```

The code actually works so I was happy... until I realized SecKeyDecrypt is not available on OSX.  So I tried this...

```
// Create the SecKeyRef
CFMutableDictionaryRef parameters = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, NULL, NULL);
CFDictionarySetValue(parameters, kSecAttrKeyType, kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA);
CFDictionarySetValue(parameters, kSecAttrKeyClass, kSecAttrKeyClassPrivate);
SecKeyRef key = SecKeyCreateFromData(parameters, (__bridge CFDataRef)keyData, &error);

// And decrypt.  Error handling removed from code segment
SecTransformRef decrypt = SecDecryptTransformCreate(key, &error);
SecTransformSetAttribute(decrypt, kSecPaddingKey, kSecPaddingNoneKey, &error);       // Sorta works
SecTransformSetAttribute(decrypt, kSecTransformInputAttributeName, (__bridge CFDataRef)encryptedData, &error);
CFDataRef decryptedData = SecTransformExecute(decrypt, &error);
```

This actually *nearly* works.  If I input 128 bytes of encrypted data, it decrypts it correctly but pads the decrypted with 0 at the beginning of the block.  So the actual data decrypted is 100 bytes.  So I end up with

```
[ 28 bytes of 0s ][Correct decrypted data]
```

So a few questions.  How can I tell how to many initial 0s to chop off from the decrypted data?  Or is there some way to not pad the decrypted data?

Thanks

-- Update --

Okay was lurking in the Mac documentation and found a comment that said "No Padding" schema is not valid for encrypted data that begins with 0.  So, I told our Java team we need to pad with:

```
    PKCS1Encoding eng = new PKCS1Encoding(new RSAEngine());
    eng.init(true, keys.getPublic());
    byte[] result = eng.processBlock(data, 0, data.length);
```

and I changed my iOS decryption code to

```
    status = SecKeyDecrypt( key, kSecPaddingPKCS1, ( uint8_t*)[ data bytes], [ data length], plainBuffer, &plainBufferSize);
```

and everything worked fine.  So, I changed the OSX code to:

```
    SecTransformRef decrypt = SecDecryptTransformCreate(key, &error);
    SecTransformSetAttribute(decrypt, kSecPaddingKey, kSecPaddingPKCS1Key, &error);      
    SecTransformSetAttribute(decrypt, kSecTransformInputAttributeName, (__bridge CFDataRef)data, &error);
    NSData *decryptedData = CFBridgingRelease(SecTransformExecute(decrypt, &error));
```

and expected it to work... however it throws this error

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-2147415748 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -2147415748 - CSSMERR_CSP_INVALID_ATTR_PADDING)" UserInfo=0x6080002750c0 {NSDescription=CSSMERR_CSP_INVALID_ATTR_PADDING}
```

Any ideas?

-- Update 2 --
Here is a dumpasn1 of a sample private key

```
  0  604: SEQUENCE {
   4    1:   INTEGER 0
   7  129:   INTEGER
         :     00 85 ED 90 D9 01 6E 9A 55 97 54 8F 0F 18 CB B5
         :     E4 22 5F CE 8C 15 5E 1B 87 D3 95 4A 38 6D 22 69
         :     DC 66 47 21 08 0F 37 AD 7D 60 F9 56 8B 84 6F 73
         :     F6 37 63 45 61 E8 BF F7 D5 47 CE 5B 49 60 17 65
         :     6C FD 0F AF AD E9 65 AD D5 9C 7E 3F EF 7E 51 4A
         :     02 49 97 83 3A CF 24 B8 EF 50 8C 1D 00 B1 15 27
         :     6E BD 91 E5 62 B0 62 78 97 6F 08 5D 76 C9 86 74
         :     6C 7C 00 C7 CB 28 45 6C 96 F6 42 CD 83 05 F2 45
         :             [ Another 1 bytes skipped ]
 139    3:   INTEGER 65537
 144  128:   INTEGER
         :     18 95 79 27 3C 6A 0F 0E 73 0E E4 8B C2 E3 71 EA
         :     04 9D 4D 8E CD 45 4F 0C 69 BC 57 B9 6F DF 07 4B
         :     9B C2 A6 BF 91 FB 88 6F 21 63 E3 8D 0C AC 60 BE
         :     EB 7F DF 76 8F 80 DD 7F 5B 04 F8 20 C9 F0 C1 7F
         :     32 22 36 C1 F7 38 13 4B 40 F7 85 AC B2 3F 49 AC
         :     3A C7 43 89 BD 7B CE 7F BE 02 AD B6 04 8C 22 A0
         :     1F 64 98 36 D9 C4 BC 9C A7 9F 0C 86 48 29 57 13
         :     BD 36 97 BF 13 51 19 BE 8A C8 DD DD 0E 77 DE 11
 275   65:   INTEGER
         :     00 B9 51 A5 C1 29 A0 CF F6 3C 68 FF BC 94 60 A0
         :     43 65 56 8A BA 1E 11 7A A0 6D 76 66 7D C6 B2 34
         :     C9 1A 59 D4 13 96 F4 C5 E3 8A C8 E0 84 2D 78 9F
         :     46 0E 26 B9 DD 13 93 0A 12 34 DE 76 C9 B7 6D 67
         :     2F
 342   65:   INTEGER
         :     00 B9 02 28 A6 45 11 1F AF 5C 9E 7E 75 BC 30 2A
         :     29 06 FE 66 54 52 79 2C F4 02 92 09 92 FF 73 59
         :     E4 8A 8F B5 22 9F CC CF E9 78 52 4B EE B8 D5 33
         :     7B B6 B5 38 28 27 2A 0A AE 89 D2 21 65 C0 FC 88
         :     E5
 409   64:   INTEGER
         :     6B CC 2C A9 01 F8 03 40 6E BF 7D 13 4B 14 31 E5
         :     42 4B 67 03 00 7E 96 60 3F 8C 41 EE 23 E8 81 80
         :     01 8E 03 29 2A 04 54 20 1A 18 E3 50 BF CA 8C 8B
         :     89 AB C9 2D EA 36 FC 02 BF 32 30 D3 01 99 E8 0D
 475   64:   INTEGER
         :     79 08 D3 85 2B 6C 2F 79 6F 33 75 72 1A E2 BB C2
         :     49 84 07 78 24 D8 87 B3 3F 37 41 32 3D 12 BE FD
         :     88 34 CA 00 D3 E0 8F 28 A3 81 DB 91 5A B4 88 50
         :     E8 50 18 64 14 73 29 B7 D4 0C 77 B2 F5 15 81 8D
 541   65:   INTEGER
         :     00 A6 73 29 DC BC 09 91 FF 14 54 DA 80 20 94 80
         :     D6 D5 5D E0 84 2E C8 F4 F0 D5 27 90 9B C5 BE 4D
         :     48 C3 6A 2B 74 E7 16 E2 44 93 C3 33 FC AA DE CA
         :     5E 45 97 C3 B2 3F 7A FE 5A A6 F9 8F A2 7D B9 CF
         :     AD
         :   }
```

Comment: Given that this is a non-obvious answer, and likely useful to future readers, move your solution to an answer and accept it (you can accept your own answers, and it is appropriate to do so in this case).

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am trying to make a simple RSA decryption on a Mac OS X app, and I cannot get it to work correctly. The documentation says that 
`SecKeyCreateFromData`"Constructs a SecKeyRef object for a *symmetric* key", so I am not sure if that is the trouble is.

Comment: care to share how you generated the `key` object you pass into `SecKeyDecrypt` in iOS from your byte array? Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was answered by Apple support.  Search their CryptoCompatibility sample code for "rdar://problem/13661366" and you'll find this:

```
    // For an RSA key the transform does PKCS#1 padding by default.  Weirdly, if we explicitly
    // set the padding to kSecPaddingPKCS1Key then the transform fails <rdar://problem/13661366>>. 
    // Thus, if the client has requested PKCS#1, we leave paddingStr set to NULL, which prevents
    // us explicitly setting the padding to anything, which avoids the error while giving us
    // PKCS#1 padding.
```

So the fix is:

```
SecTransformSetAttribute(decrypt, kSecPaddingKey, NULL, &error);
```

OR

We actually ended up using OAEP padding